# Python: Record Audio File with pyaudio while waiting for user input

Tags: python, pyaudio

I would like to start recording microphone input with pyaudio, wait for user keyboard input, then stop the recording and write the recorded audio to disk.

The script below is as far as I got, but `vocrec_write()` gives me an error. How do I write the audio file to disk?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pyaudio, signal, sys
global mic_stream

voc_frames=[]

def vocrec_callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    global voc_frames
    voc_frames.append(in_data)
    return (in_data, pyaudio.paContinue)

def vocrec_start():
    global mic_stream
    voc_rate=44100
    mic_stream = pa.open(format=pa.get_format_from_width(2),
                    channels=1 if sys.platform == 'darwin' else 2,
                    rate=voc_rate,
                    input=True,
                    output=False,
                    stream_callback=vocrec_callback)
    return mic_stream

def vocrec_stop():
    mic_stream.close()
    pa.terminate()

def vocrec_write():
    with open("output.wav", "wb") as file:
        file.write(voc_frames)

class SIGINT_handler():
    def __init__(self):
        self.SIGINT = False
    def signal_handler(self, signal, frame):
        self.SIGINT = True
        print('You pressed Ctrl+C!')
        vocrec_stop()
        quit()

def get_data ():
    vocrec_start()
    user_input = input("Enter text: ")
    vocrec_stop()
    # here I would like to dump the recorded data to disk
    vocrec_write()
    # but i get this error
    # 'TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'list''
    quit()

handler = SIGINT_handler()
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler.signal_handler)
pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()

get_data()
```

Comment: You would need some kind of parallelism here. Multiprocessing could help you. One process records, while one process waits for the user input. Could you provide your code, which is recording without waiting for user input? Maybe I can help you out then, modifying that.

Comment: Thanks, Yannick. I think pyaudio's stream command runs async, but I can't write it to file. Here's the code I have so far: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l2z5hdfceg9bxte/code.py?dl=0

Comment: I won't  open any dropbox links, please add a minimal reproducible example to your question

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow and thought I'd have to enter code in comments, which length did not allow. Updated the main post now. Thanks again.

Comment: you are trying to write a list of frames to your file. Try iterating over the list and write every frame separately